# visualstudio 2010 VB.NET customizing the code automatically displayed when I write New

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

When in a code editor I write

```
Sub New (enter)
```

The editor automatically inserts:

```
Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

How can I customize the code it writes? Can't find it in the code snippets manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string is baked into Common7\IDE\1033\msvb7ui.dll.  In other words, it is hard-coded in the binary code that implements the VB.NET IDE.

This is also the case for the auto-generated code when you implement IDisposable.  Much worse actually since that code is inappropriate 99.9% of the time.

If it *really* annoys you, you could use File + Open + File and navigate to the DLL.  Open the string table and double-click "String Table".  It is string #1059.  Note that you cannot change the line spacing or the comment.  Do make sure you make a backup of the file, I didn't try it myself.

Comment: No, I won't touch the dll. In Netbeans I remember I could easily configure this behaviour editing the templates (simple text files).